# jQuery Mobile doesn't load on JSON ajax result

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, mobile

I'm trying to load the jQuery Mobile 'styles' (in this case the buttons).

Here is my HTML code (ajax):

```
<!-- jQuery + Mobile (LOCAL) -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../jquery.mobile/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
<script src="../../jquery.mobile/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>

<script>

$.ajax({
            type : "GET",
            url : "http://localhost/asistencia/mant/scripts/s_m_zona.php?id_zona="+id_zona,
            async : true,
            success : function(datos) {
                var dataJson = eval(datos);
                for ( i in dataJson) {
                    // SOME CODE HEDE


                    // GUARDAR NOMBRE ZONA
                    $("#btn_guardar").html("<button data-ajax='false' onclick='GuardarNombreZona("+dataJson[i].id_zona+");return false;'>Modificar nombre </button>");

                    $("#botones").html("<button data-ajax='false' onclick='Remover("+dataJson[i].id_zona+")'>Crear nueva área</button>");
                    $("#crearnuevo").button('refresh');
                }

            },
            error : function(obj, error, objError) {
                //avisar que ocurrió un error
                alert("ERROR DE RED");
            }

        });

</script>

<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="index">
        <div data-role="header">
            <a href="../index.html" data-icon="back" data-iconpos="notext" rel="external"  data-transition="fade">Volver</a>
            <h3> Modificar zona </h3>
        </div> <!-- header -->

        <div data-role="content">
            <!-- <div id="zonas">
            </div> <br/> -->
            <div id="botones">
            </div>
            <table>
                    <tr>
                    <td>Zona: <input type="text" id="zona_name" name="zona_name" /></td>
                    <td><div id="btn_guardar"></div></td>
                    </tr>
            </table>
        </div> <!-- content -->
    </div>
</body>
```

The buttons on **#btn_guardar** and **#botones** divs show like any button and don't displays the CSS from jquery mobile.

Thank you for answers, sry for bad english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `trigger("create");` after putting the html of the buttons on the parent :

```
$("#btn_guardar").html("<button data-ajax='false' onclick='GuardarNombreZona("+dataJson[i].id_zona+");return false;'>Modificar nombre </button>");
$("#btn_guardar").trigger("create");

$("#botones").html("<button data-ajax='false' onclick='Remover("+dataJson[i].id_zona+")'>Crear nueva área</button>");
$("#botones").trigger("create");
```